# Python Script to Export Columns and Rows from Query to CSV

Tags: python, csv, hive, hiveql

I've searched several forums and unable to find an exact answer. I'm connecting to a Hive DB, running the query in Python, and exporting the results to a .csv but only been able to return the rows, no column headers.  Please see sample code below.  Thanks for your help!

```
    import pyhs2
    import csv

    with pyhs2.connect(host='host',
    port=10000,
    authMechanism="PLAIN",
    user='username',
    password='password',
    database='default') as conn:

    with conn.cursor() as cur:
      cur.execute("select * from table limit 100")
      result = cur.fetchall()
      c = csv.writer(open("temp.csv", "wb"))

    for row in result:
      c.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Looking [here](https://qnalist.com/questions/5910281/pyhs2-get-column-header-from-result-set), it sounds like `cur.getSchema()` might get you the column headings.

Comment: thank you @AndrewPiliser. to then write the column header and results to .csv would the code look something similar to this?        c.writerow(cur.getSchema())

Comment: No idea, see what you get from cur.getSchema and if you need to parse or manipulate it.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewPiliser I will give that a try